# Replace the value inside a csv column by value inside parentheses of the same column using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I got the following csv file with sample data:
[image: Small part of the csv file with sample data]

Now I want to replace the columns 'SIFT' and 'PolyPhen' values with the data inside the parentheses of these columns. So for row 1 the SIFT value will replace to 0.82, and for row 2 the SIFT value will be 0.85. Also I want the part before the parentheses, tolerated/deleterious, inside a new column named 'SIFT_prediction'.

This is what I tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

testfile = 'test_sift_columns.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(testfile)  
df['SIFT'].re.search(r'\((.*?)\)',s).group(1)
```

This code will take everything inside the parentheses of the column SIFT. But this does not replace anything. I probably need a for loop to read and replace every row but I don't know how to do it correctly. Also I am not sure if using a regular expression is necessary with pandas. Maybe there is a smarter way to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SIFT':['tol(0.82)','tol(0.85)','tol(1.42)'],
                   'PolyPhen':['beg(0)','beg(0)','beg(0)']})

pat = r'(.*?)\((.*?)\)'
df[['SIFT_prediction','SIFT']] = df['SIFT'].str.extract(pat)
df[['PolyPhen_prediction','PolyPhen']] = df['PolyPhen'].str.extract(pat)

print(df)
  SIFT_prediction  SIFT PolyPhen_prediction PolyPhen
0             tol  0.82                 beg        0
1             tol  0.85                 beg        0
2             tol  1.42                 beg        0
```

Alternative:

```
df[['SIFT_prediction','SIFT']] = df['SIFT'].str.rstrip(')').str.split('(', expand=True)
df[['PolyPhen_prediction','PolyPhen']] = df['PolyPhen'].str.rstrip(')').str.split('(', expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, will this replace all rows in the column and add the new column back to the testfile?

Comment: @Yoni - Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like replacing all alphanumeric values with empty strings in order to get the float value and the opposite to get the predicion.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4], 'SIFT': ['tolerated(0.82)', 'tolerated(0.85)', 'tolerated(0.25)', 'dedicated(0.5)']})
df['SIFT_formatted'] = df.SIFT.str.replace('[^0-9.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df['SIFT_prediction'] = df.SIFT.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '', regex=True)
df
```

Would give you:

```
    ID  SIFT            SIFT_formatted  SIFT_prediction
0   1   tolerated(0.82) 0.82             tolerated
1   2   tolerated(0.85) 0.85             tolerated
2   3   tolerated(0.25) 0.25             tolerated
3   4   dedicated(0.5)  0.50             dedicated
```